# C# UWP: Access a textblock and status of check box inside a listview

Tags: c#, uwp

Hi I have my list view as follows:
![][1]

```
<RelativePanel >
    <ListView x:Name="StudentListView"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              Width="1000"
              ItemClick="Student_ItemClick" >
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ABC">
            <StackPanel 
                 x:Name="ListItemPanel"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"  
                 MaxWidth="500">
                 <TextBlock  x:Name ="uName" Text="{Binding Username}" 
                            Margin="20,0,20,8"
                            FontSize="24" 
                            FontStyle="Italic" 
                            FontWeight="SemiBold"
                            Foreground="DarkBlue" 
                            /> 
                 <CheckBox Name="AttendCheckBox" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Checked="AttendCheckBox_Checked" 
                           IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
    <TextBlock Name="queryName" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>

    <Button Name="finishBtn" Content="Finish" RelativePanel.Below="StudentListView" ></Button>
</RelativePanel>
```

I am trying to access each data item and check if checkbox is checked or not when user clicks on finish button that is on same page as `listview`. And I am having tough time trying to figure it out. Any hint on it would be great. Thank you

Comment: How are you trying to check?  Also, it's not recommended to post code as an image but rather copy and paste it directly into the question in a code block.  Others may want to copy it out to test it for you or fix it for proper working code.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thank you for swift reply, I am trying to access each item on listview whenever the "finish" button is clicked. Access each item and then see if the checkbox in each item is checked or not and then pass all the checked item to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code. You did not need to use `Checked` event of CheckBox. Instead, you could declare a bool type property in your custom class and bind `IsChecked` to it and set `Mode=TwoWay`, then, once your checkbox's `IsChecked` value is changed, the source also will be updated. After that, you could filter the source to get the 'IsChecked=True' items.

According to your code snippet, I made a code sample for you reference:

```
<RelativePanel>
        <ListView x:Name="StudentListView"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                      Width="1000" Height="500">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ABC">
                <StackPanel 
                            x:Name="ListItemPanel"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"  
                            MaxWidth="500">
                    <TextBlock  x:Name ="uName" Text="{Binding Username}" 
                                   Margin="20,0,20,8"
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   FontStyle="Italic" 
                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                   Foreground="DarkBlue"/>
                    <CheckBox Name="AttendCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Name="queryName" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>

        <Button Name="finishBtn" Content="Finish" RelativePanel.Below="StudentListView" Click="{x:Bind finishBtn_Click}"></Button>
    </RelativePanel>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public ObservableCollection<Test> tests { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            tests.Add(new Test() {Username="name "+i });
        }
        StudentListView.ItemsSource = tests;
    }

    private void finishBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedStudents = tests.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).ToList();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _Username; }
        set
        {
            if (_Username != value)
            {
                _Username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsSelected != value)
            {
                _IsSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```